# Sql query total of subquery sums (Laravel)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query:

```
InvoiceLine::selectRaw('billable_name as name')
                ->selectRaw('cast(sum(quantity) as unsigned) as pcs')
                ->selectRaw('cast(sum((unit_price + environmental_tax) / 100) as unsigned) as sub_sum')
                ->where('billable_type', 'like', '%Product')
                ->groupByRaw('billable_name')
                ->orderBy('name')
                ->paginate(20)
```

I would like receive in every query the total sum of sub_sum.
Of course without paginate, I simply take the result and sum all sub_sum, but in this case it does not work.
My other idea is two query with union. In the second without paginate and others, only sum of sub_sum.
But maybe there is other way...

The result now:

```
name, pcs, sub_sum
name, pcs, sub_sum
...
```

I would like to get the sum of all sub_sums.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you describe your problem? quite hard to understand without context

Comment: Sorry. My english not very well. I supplement my asking.